# Multiple Excel Manipulation Using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I need to manipulate multiple excel files and as per my research powershell would be the best way to do so. Here's my question.

I have probably more that 500+ excel files containing a similar format to the screenshot below.

[image: Sample Excel File Screenshot]

Each excel file has 2 sheets. What really matter is the data on sheet 2 which contains the data. I would like to auto insert a value for the Branch column which you could see is blank. The branch would be taken from cell B2. I would really help of I could manipulate all the 500+ excel files in one run. Hope you could help. Also, the 500+ excel files have different filenames but have the same format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell can indeed do this fairly easily. First you get the list of files, then you launch Excel, and in a ForEach loop you open the file, find the value of B2, apply it in all B column cells for rows 5 and over that are used. Then save and close that file, and move to the next one. At the end we close Excel.

```
#Get list of files
$Files = Get-ChildItem c:\Path\To\Files\*.xlsx

#Launch Excel
$XL = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

ForEach($File in $Files){
    #Open the file and get the Data sheet
    $WB = $XL.Workbooks.Open($File.Fullname)
    $Sheet = $WB.Worksheets.Item('Data')

    #Get the value from B2
    $Branch = $Sheet.Rows.Item(2).Cells.Item(2).Value2

    #Loop through rows, skipping the first 4, and set the branch value
    $($Sheet.UsedRange.Rows) | Select -Skip 4 | ForEach{ $_.Cells.Item(2).Value2 = $Branch }

    #Save and close the file
    $WB.Save()
    $WB.Close($true)
}

#Close Excel
$XL.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a code in vba.
It needs input in the form of the filenames and paths and it will open each excel file write the required data in required place and then save it and close it. (Considering all the 500 files are located in one folder and there are no other files in that folder.) In the updated portion I try to [get filesnames along with paths](http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/03/05/list-files-and-folders-in-a-directory/) for all the 500 files which are located in one folder and continue the opening and editing. **Dont forget to update the folder path.**

```
Sub Open_n_Edit()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim filenames(500) As String

'Updated portion'
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("Put here the path for the folder containing 500 excel files without \ at end")
i = 1
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    filenames(i) = objFile.Path
    i = i + 1
Next objFile
'updated portion'

For i = 1 To 500
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=filenames(i)
    Lastrow = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row
    Range("B5:B" & Lastrow) = Range("B2").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you very much @Ethun_Hunt.. I would try to study this since I have no experience working with VBA.

Comment: updates: Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object- defined error

Comment: @Michelle Santos, the error is most probably because you did not provide the filenames in the array. To ease the task of getting the list of files I included the code to do that in vba itself. Hope this works now for you.

Comment: Hi @Ethun_Hunt here's my update.. Runtime Error 9, subscript out of range.. I made sure to provide the correct file path and ended it with a \.. I used the same location I declared on the powershell script I was trying to make which works fine.. the vba script can't seem to find the location..